# Why Pattern not returning true

Tags: java, regex

Regex formed with rules:

1.Start with 1

2.End with b or B.

For Eg. 101b

OR

1. Can start with 0b or 0B
2. Then will have 1

For Eg. 0b1000101

```
Pattern patternForBin=Pattern.compile("(^(1)[0-1]*(b|B)$)");
```

This regex returns true with "101b" but when I tried same with `|`

```
Pattern patternForBin=Pattern.compile("(^(0b|B)1[0-1]*) | (^(1)[0-1]*(b|B)$)");
```

Why pattern didn't match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove space from regex from both side of `|`, it a valid character for match inside regex

```
Pattern patternForBin=Pattern.compile("(^(0b|B)1[0-1]*)|(^(1)[0-1]*(b|B)$)");
```

FullCode:

```
Pattern patternForBin=Pattern.compile("(^(0b|B)1[0-1]*)|(^(1)[0-1]*(b|B)$)");
Matcher matcher = patternForBin.matcher("101b");
boolean matchFound = matcher.find();
System.out.println(matchFound);
```

Output: `true`

Answer (score 2):

There are space characters (`' '`) in the regex. In regex, whitespace is not ignored. The regular expression is trying to match the spaces in the expression so it doesn't match.